# Большая задержка(пауза) в Java

Tags: java

Делаю Java приложения. Возникла необходимость при выполнении определенных условий делать паузу выполнения программы на длительное время(час или даже больше). 
Код выполняется отдельном потоке.
На сколько правильно будет использовать для такой большой паузы

```
Thread.sleep(*очень большое число*)
```

Может быть есть другой, более правильный способ?

Comment: В теории может возникнуть `InterruptedException`. Может лучше использовать что-то вроде `Timer`, `TimerTask`?

Comment: Мало чего, приложение может и закрыться за этот час.

Comment: @metalurgus `timer` запускает отдельный поток через какое-то время, но не ставит программу на паузу. Чтобы приостановить главный поток придёт придумать как его синхронизировать с таймером. Выйдет сложнее `sleep`

Comment: @Sergey, я подразумевал, что сама по себе идея *приостановить главный поток* ужасна

Comment: @metalurgus если бы это было так ужасно, как пугают некоторые, то не было бы никакого sleep

Comment: @Sergey, Вы мне еще скажите, что использовать `goto` - это не смертный грех. К тому же, во второстепенном потоке - используйте `sleep` сколько влезет. Но если вы хотите использовать его в главном - это неправильно, мерзко и ужасно по определению.

Comment: @metalurgus И скажу. goto - совсем не грех, и уж тем более не смертный. И часто он выигрывает у других альтернатив. Что касается sleep в данном вопросе, то на самом деле требуется прояснение вопроса. Скорее требуется автору подсказать как иначе спроектировать прогу, чем пытаться изобразить паузу таймером. Может вообще надо запускать по расписанию из ОС (через cron, scheduler) и никаких sleep, timer

Comment: @Sergey, мне, честно, не о чем с вами говорить, если вы считаете нормальным использование `goto` и `sleep` в главном потоке. Будте добры не подходить ко мне на расстояние ближе 100км.

Comment: //Может вообще надо запускать по расписанию из ОС (через cron, scheduler) и никаких sleep, timer - Нет, такой вариант не подойдет. Да, паузу нужно делать НЕ в основном, а во второстепенном потоке.

Comment: Тогда правильнее переделать так, чтобы использовать таймеры. Второй поток выполнил часть работы, завершился. Продолжение запускается таймером. Как об это твердят metalurgus в комментариях и Mikhailov Valentine в своём ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее будет воспользоваться таймером или ScheduledExecutor(ом) например вот так:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("do task");
            }
        }, 0, 100);
```

---

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
        () -> { System.out.println("do task"); }, 
       0, 1,
       TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: Что делает программа после выполнения `t.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` или `service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)`? Она же продолжает выполняться, а по условию задачи должна остановится. Сделать какую-то синхронизацию с задачей? Но чем это тогда хуже `sleep`, кроме того, что будет задействовано два потока вместо одного в sleep?

Comment: @Sergey, может и продолжить и остановится, опишите поподробнее, что подразумевается под "остановится"?

Comment: Вопрос внимательней прочитайте. Нужно сделать `паузу выполнения программы`. Ваше решение сделает паузу? Сомнительно

Comment: @Sergey, честно говоря без Вашего комментария я бы этого из вопроса не понял. Больше всего смущает "Код выполняется отдельном потоке.", ну да ладно, тогда пожалуй sleep будет проще.

Comment: Тоже смущает. Короче фиг его знает чего им нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

Comment: InterruptedException никогда не должен глотаться. Представьте, что автор сейчас воспользуется вашим советом и поместит свой код (который должен выполниться через час) сразу за вашим; в этом случае interrupt спровоцирует его выполнение раньше требуемого времени.

Answer (score 0):

```
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
    TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1);
    TimeUnit.DAYS.sleep(1);
```

такое не устраивает ?