# Задержка вызывается не в нужное время java

Tags: java, многопоточность, sleep

У меня есть программа в которой нужно сделать мигание кнопок, но задержка суммируется и выполняется в начале кода не в нужное время

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    btn1.setText(" ");
    btn2.setText(" ");
    btn3.setText(" ");
    Thread.sleep(250);
    btn1.setText("X");
    btn2.setText("X");
    btn3.setText("X");
    Thread.sleep(250);
}
```

При выполнении происходит задержка 1,5 секунд и только потом меняется текст на кнопках. Он меняется очень быстро поэтому смену даже нельзя заметить. Для графического интерфейса использую `javax.swing`. Есть ли способы исправить эту проблему не создавая дополнительный поток?

Comment: Какую библиотеку для интерфейса вы используете? Swing? Или это в андроиде что-то?

Comment: А вот ещё один похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543652/%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2-java?rq=1

Comment: Ещё можно посмотреть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java-swing

Comment: В приложениях с графическим интерфейсом не стоит использовать `Thread.sleep`. Варианты решения проблемы: 1-ый способ (лёгкий)используйте `java.util.Timer` 2-ой способ (сложный)Создавайте отдельный поток